# Docker Container IPv6 Messages Can be Received but not Transmited

Tags: docker, docker-compose, udp, ipv6, coap

I'm trying to containerize an application that communicates with nodes on an IPv6 WPAN network.  When I run my application on the bare OS I can TX and RX on the network and the IP addresses in the packets I receive match nodes on the WPAN.  When run in a container, I can receive messages from the nodes but the IP addresses and port number in the messages don't match any nodes and trying to TX or ping nodes on the WPAN return as unreachable.  The [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/) was light on IPv6 so I am not sure if I have something configured wrong.

**My network config in the docker-compose.yml**

```
networks:
   default:
       driver: bridge
       enable_ipv6: true
       ipam:
          driver: default
         config:
           - subnet: 2001:3984:4989::/64
             gateway: 2001:3984:4989::1
```

**Ports mapping for container**

```
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5683:5683/udp"
```

**RX snip from a CoAP message from server running on container**

```
rsinfo: {
   address: '::ffff:192.168.80.1',
   family: 'IPv6',
   port: 51028,
   size: 13
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the preferred way (since it does not actually bridge the WPAN and docker network), but I was able to connect by removing my "networks.default" section and adding "network_mode: host".  This caused a bit of an issue though because I couldn't resolve other container names unless I added "network_mode: host" to each container.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer. But maybe the same issue with IPv4 :-). https://github.com/eclipse/californium/issues/1353#issuecomment-650522367. So, if you have a solution, I will be really interested in it!